# Does the Windows Qt binary installer support DBus out of the box?

Tags: c++, windows, qt, ipc, dbus

**Does the Windows Qt binary installer support DBus out of the box?**

Specifically:

- version 4.x
- version 4.7.x
- version 4.8.x

NOTE: Version 5.x is still in active development so I won't include 5.x as part of this question.

Comment: speaking about things that are still in development it's never a good thing; for what i know the 5.x branch is public ( because qt sources are public ) but it's not officially released yet.

Comment: @user1797612 thanks for the tip. I modified the question as per your suggestion.

Answer (score 4):

**All 4.x version of Windows Qt binary installer do not support DBus out of the box.**

Specifically for the version requested in the question:

- ["Unix-only" 4.7.x](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-4.7/modules.html)
- ["Unix-only" 4.8.x](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-4.8/modules.html)
- all other 4.x versions are "Unix-only" too

Go here for information on Qt 5.x's DBus support [QtDbus 5.x support](https://qt-project.org/doc/qt-5/qtdbus-module.html). 5.x is still in development so I will leave a link instead of copying what is written there.

---

Bonus:

Historically DBus did not work on Windows in the past and that is why the QtDbus module was not available for Windows. More recently [the Windows version of DBus is now working and supported](http://www.freedesktop.org/wiki/Software/dbus#Windows_port). Unfortunately Qt has not updated their 4.x Windows Qt binary installers to reflect DBus now working on Windows.

Long story short, now that Windows DBus works [you can compile Qt yourself and get access to the QtDbus module on Windows](http://www.lothlorien.com/kf6gpe/?p=141). I have not done this yet myself.

Comment: UPDATE: I have successfully gotten QtDbus on Windows to work. It requires many hours to configure IMO. (Here's a short summary flossing over MANY details: 1. download qt source 2. download dbus source 3. download/install cmake 4. build dbus 5. modify/configure qt build to point to built dbus 6. build qt 7. write custom code to start dbus-daemon (dbus windows code doesn't auto start dbus-daemon like in unix) 8. done)